# Changing password by dscl causes an iCloud re-login

Tags: macos, icloud, password, monterey

When I changed my account password using the `dscl` command, everything worked fine, but if I logged out of the account then logged in again, an iCloud popup appears: "This Mac can't connect with iCloud because a problem with <apple_id>".

I then need to re-enter the iCloud password.

If I change the password using System Settings UI this doesn't happen.

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Comment: Use `security set-keychain-password` will fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your keychain password is not the same as your account password. Use the system preferences gui for password changes for accounts with iCloud and iCloud Keychain involvement.

I’m guessing you’re [looking for a deeper link between iCloud and the command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441486/is-there-a-command-to-check-apple-id-status-on-macos), though than just to avoid the prompt.

Comment: not my intention, i just want to change password by command line without affect any running application (even if the mac restarts). But maybe somehow they're related.

Comment: You can use `passwd` to change passwords, but the next time you try a graphical log in, the keychain will be locked / pop up a dialog to enter the keychain password. I wouldn’t mess with dscl for that task unless you needed to @cdfxhn